# Advanced BC Calc level derivative

Tags: calculus

I am currently taking BC Calculus as a freshman, and I came across this problem that none of the teachers in my school knew how to do:
Find $dy/dx$ of $y = {{{(7+x)}^{(7+x)}}^{y}}^{2}$:
I was going through, changing the exponents, and got to $(7+x)^{(7+x)2y}$. After taking log base $7+x$ on both sides, I get $(7+x)2y = \log_{7+x} y$. Then, using the change of base formula, I got $\log(y) = (7+x)2y\log(7+x)$. I couldn't go any further. If you have any hints, please supply those first because I want to try to figure this out by myself.

Comment: You'll need to clarify the given equation. See the **Groups** section in the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Also, we particularly are unclear- are you doing $a^{(b^c)}$ or $(a^b)^c$?  Please specify for all 4 levels of powers.  Note: These different expressions result in different numbers.
Ex. $x^{(2^3)} = x^8$ but ${(x^2)}^3 = x^2 \cdot x^2 \cdot x^2 = x^6$

Comment: I can fix your math formatting, but unfortunately the question is likely to be closed.  Unfortunately, I think Math.SE is likely to close your question due to the ambiguity I mentioned.  You can edit your post with the "Edit" button.
You're looking for some variation of  a^{(b^x)} but begin and end with dollar signs, \$.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the brackets of the original function is $$y=\left(\left((7+x)^{(7+x)}\right)^y\right)^2$$So then we get $$y=(7+x)^{2y(7+x)}$$Following what you wrote, assuming you made no mistakes. Take the derivative of both sides: $$y'=(7+x)^{2y(7+x)}\ln(7+x)y'$$Dividing both sides by $y'$, it becomes clear how to solve for $y$: $$y=-\frac1{2(7+x)}\log_{7+x}\left(\ln(7+x)\right)=\frac1{2(7+x)}\frac{\ln\ln(7+x)}{\ln(7+x)}$$Taking the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$ gives us the answer. This will take a while, but using quotient rule you'll be able to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: simplify the exponents:

$$y = (7 + x)^{(7 + x)^{2y}}$$

I'm going to simplify $r = 7 + x$ so I don't have to keep writing it.  So we have:

$$ y = r^{r^{2y}} $$

From here, you can do it in two ways.  Either (a) logarithmic differentiation (where you take the log of both sides so you can remove the exponents) or (b) using the generalized power rule.  I'm going to guess they wanted you to use logarithmic differentiation.

$$ \ln(y) = \ln(r^{r^{2y}}) \\
\ln(y) = r^{2y}\ln(r) \\
\frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(r)} = r^2y \\
\ln\left(\frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(r)}\right) = \ln(r^2y) \\
\ln\left(\frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(r)}\right) = 2y \ln(r) \\
$$

From here you can do implicit differentiation for the results.

For the Generalized Power Rule, the derivative of $u^v$ with respect to $x$ is:

$$\ln(u)\,u^v\,\frac{dv}{dx} + vu^{v - 1}\,\frac{du}{dx}$$

As you can see, it is just a combination of the power rule and the exponentiation rule.  If you apply it twice with $u$-substitution you should get the answer you are looking for.  It's a real mess but it works.